# File.mkdirs() does not create the folders - Android Marshmallow (API 23)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, mkdirs

Android Manifest Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Java file (First try)

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/newAppFolder";
File dir = new File(path);
dir.mkdirs();
```

Java file (Second try)

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "newAppFolder");
    if(!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Folder Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Folder exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

else
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SD Card Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Unfortunately neither attempt creates the newAppFolder file that I need. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Note: In the second try, the application toast keeps showing Folder Created

Comment: If your target sdk is 23, you should check [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) and see if requesting permission at runtime fixes it.

Comment: @Vucko I don't think that could be the issue as "Folder Created" is displayed.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari can you see that that toast will be displayed if the folder does not exist, and if `mkdirs()` does not throw an exception? It will display the toast even if the folder's not actually created.

Comment: @Vucko That's what I meant, lack of permissions would have lead to the exception and Toast would not have been visible.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari you're quite right. I have no idea what other thing it may be then..

Comment: @Vucko Thank you very much. That was the problem. It all works fine now

Comment: No problem at all bro. I'll move my comment to the answer then, and you can accept it so it may help the others if a day comes and someone else stumbles upon the same problem.
Apparently, it does not throw the Exception, just silently failes @ShadabAnsari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (**API level 23**), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

If your target sdk is 23, you should check [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) and see if requesting permission at runtime fixes it.